# Javascript dropdown no longer working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/928Dj/39/

```
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function (e) {
    var cache = $(this).next('ul');
    $('#filter ul:visible').not(cache).hide();
    cache.toggle();
});
```

There is no error in the console. In my html I moved the `form` outside of the `ul`, from what I can see the javascript is still valid but the dropdown is no longer triggered when I click the link. Where is the error in the code?

Comment: `var cache = $(this).next().find('ul');` - or just avoid using `next()` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replaced the line #3 from your code to

`var cache = $(this).next('form').find('ul');`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/43/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `next()` isn't a `ul`.

`next()` will get the next sibling, since `next()` isn't a `ul` it (`next("ul")`) will not contain an element.

Since the `ul` you want to get is a child of the next sibling, try this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmTJd/)

```
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function (e) {
    var cache = $(this).next('form').find("ul");
    $('#filter ul:visible').not(cache).hide();
    cache.toggle();
});
```

---

**Notes:**

It doesn't appear that this would happen... but if it is possible that you may have other siblings between `a` and `form`, you could do `.nextAll('form')` and this will look at all of the siblings after the `a`.

If it is possible that you may have multiple levels of `ul` under `form`, you might want to do `.children('ul')` instead of `.find('ul')`, this way it will only look at direct children.

---

**Alternative**

This is probably how I would have done it, I've made some minor changes to all (js, html, and css):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmTJd/3/)

```
$('.dropdown').on("click", function (e) {
    var cache = $(this).siblings('.opt');
    $('.opt:visible').not(cache).hide();
    cache.toggle();
});
```

Comment: That's great thank you. I don't mean to be picky but before the dropdown would also be hidden when you clicked on the menu twice (i.e toggle) but that doesnt seem to work on your code?

Comment: @Jimmy, you can use `toggle()`, i just changed that while testing something.. i've changed it back now

Comment: @Jimmy, I've added some notes and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can use this:

```
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function (e) {
    var cache = $(this).next().children();
    $('#filter ul:visible').not(cache).hide();
    cache.toggle();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/49/)